# Data Labels of stacked column chart is not showing in Highcharts in angular project

Tags: angular, highcharts

In my angular project, I have a stacked column chart(as shown in the image). I'm facing difficulty in rendering the data labels of stacked column when the data values varies too much(as shown in the series data image).

Some Datalabels and their respective segments are also not showing in the bars.
I've tried "allowOverlap: true" but it is not working.

I'm new in this, Please help.
Below is the image of the graph and the series data code.

[image: Series Data]

[image: Stacked column chart]

Comment: Hi @Ritu Singh, Please try to enable `allowOverlap` property. Example: http://jsfiddle.net/BlackLabel/n1msgpuy/

Comment: Hi @ppotaczek , I've tried it already it is not working. It is piling up the small value data one over the other.

Comment: So how would you like to handle data labels if there is no enough space for them?

Comment: That's what my question is .. that how do I increase the space for all the data labels to render properly. For example if one value is 28268 as in above diagram, so due to which the range gas increased, now the values in 'A' and 'C' are overlapping. So i am trying to find a way in which all the values can be clearly distinguished.

Comment: You can for example individually position the data labels: http://jsfiddle.net/BlackLabel/n1msgpuy/1/

Comment: but there is not enough space for positioning also. How should I create space for relatively smaller data values? . Is there anything for increase pixels space between the smaller intervals of y-Axis. So that smaller values can adjust in stacked bar.

Comment: You can try breaks: http://jsfiddle.net/BlackLabel/n1msgpuy/2/ but the result seems to be inadequate. Another option is `minPointLength`, but it doesn't work well enough with stacking. Plese check this thread: https://github.com/highcharts/highcharts/issues/1776 to find out more and if possible, use one of the workarounds.